# Chromecast sender disconnects and reconnects automatically while the application is active?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I have attached some logs below. Why does such auto disconnect and reconnect happen?

```
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.285s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"reason\":\"`transport_closed`\",\"senderId\":\"0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693\",\"type\":\"`senderdisconnected`\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.287s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.289s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching sender disconnected event [0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693] Reason: unknown
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.292s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.294s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.296s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.testapp.chrome.cast, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.298s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.broadcast, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.300s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.302s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Unregistering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.4:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [140.305s] [cast.framework.Application] onSenderDisconnected
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.694s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"senderId\":\"0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693\",\"type\":\"`senderconnected`\",\"userAgent\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36\"}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.system","senderId":"SystemSender"}
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.695s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.699s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Dispatching CastReceiverManager sender connected event [0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.702s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.debugoverlay, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.704s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.cac, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.707s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.trialapp.chrome.cast, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.709s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.broadcast, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.712s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [141.714s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Registering sender [urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.inject, 0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:151299535132113693]
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [142.496s] [cast.receiver.IpcChannel] Received message: {"data":"{\"type\":\"GET_STATUS\",\"requestId\":174390150}","namespace":"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media","senderId":"0c131ea4-1bf8-5d01-4628-87b5e61bfb65.9:sender-gf9htjf8syr5"}
cast_receiver_framework.js:66  [142.498s] [cast.receiver.CastMessageBus] Dispatching CastMessageBus message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reason disconnects can happen. Typically, the receiver isn't responding fast enough, then the heartbeat signal won't arrive at the sender which will then force the receiver to close and disconnect. It could also be local networking issues, but for any transient networking issues, the senders will automatically reconnect to the receiver.

Comment: Yes, I was working with slow network. So missing the heartbeat signal could have been the reason.